# How to select nth item from a context menu i Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

E.g. when selecting one of completions suggested by Intellij when typing code. Using arrow keys requires relocation of right hand and simply continuing to write is slow, too.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Continue typing to narrow down the list?

Comment: @CrazyCoder as I mentioned, that can sometimes be very slow.

Comment: You can use page up/down and home/end in the focused popup

Comment: @CrazyCoder doesn't solve anything - still requires relocation of right hand.

Comment: You could use IdeaVim plug-in with the alternative navigation shortcuts instead of arrows. There is no other way, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA, if it gets enough votes for mnemonics in completion popup, we'll consider adding it.

Comment: IdeaVim plug-in helps with navigation in editor, but doesn't help with navigation in Project View or popups like Class Structure, Find Usages, Go To Implementation.. I also have this problem, having an option+ITEM_INDEX_NUMBER or smtng similar would be very helpful.. @MatějKripner did you submit feature request?

Comment: Note I have found https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9852-ijkl-shortctus which might help. Although I'd rather have hjkl instead of ijkl since I'm already training to use vim with hjkl row..